# Framemaker feature - run on paragraph styles. Is this possible in scribus?

Tags: style, scribus, paragraph

Framemaker will let you configure a paragraph style to run on after the finish of the paragraph.  This is good for hanging paragraphs where the first line is really a subheading, Excuse the monospaced text, but something like:

```
.Heading: Lorem ipsum dolor  
.    blah blah blah blah  
.    blah wibble blarg
```

Heading is a separate paragraph, and by changing the styles you could go from the above text to a separate heading like

**Heading**
Lorem ipsum dolor
blah blah blah
blah wibble blarg

I can't see anything in the docs that refer to this.  Does Scribus support this type of run-on paragraph style?

**EDIT:** Bonus points for anyone who can figure out how to make markdown do hanging paragraph headings of that sort ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, styles currently do not have “next paragraph style” option. I personally filed that request earlier this year, and it was categorized as “maybe one day” :)

Regarding hanging paragraphs... Ugh... Are we talking about setting up styles that have side spacing? :)